# How to scale element to fit in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, storyboard, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView in a storyboard.  How do I scale it so that it fills the screen regardless of which device is in use?  I figured out how to use the constraints to center it, but not to resize it.

Comment: Pin it to all the sides of the superview with whatever padding you want. If you do that, then you don't need to center it also.

Comment: That just centered it.  How do I stretch it to fit the area of the larger screen?

Comment: Pinning to all sides should make it stretch to fit all screens. If that didn't happen, then you did something incorrectly. Does the collection view have a background color so you can see what size it is? Doing this won't change the size of the cells